# SQL injection at work

Tags: sql-injection, sql-server

We have a web form that can be filled out with text fields and then they get emailed to us at work. Today we got some SQL commands it looks like in a bunch of emails. I just would like to have a bit general knowledge of what they were trying to do. I copied every command they sent through and have it below:

All I am asking is what were they trying to do?

```
&dir
--
or 1=1--
#
convert(varchar,0x7b5d)
bad_bad_value'
'+convert(int,convert(varchar,0x7b5d))+'
char(39)
convert(varchar,0x7b5d)
'
/*
convert(int,convert(varchar,0x7b5d))
'
9,9,9
convert(int,convert(varchar,0x7b5d))
' or 1=1--
%27
'+convert(varchar,0x7b5d)+'
tqedbt
and 1=1;--
x || ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 &
& ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 &
and 1=1
index.cfm
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Someone is just casually testing to see if the input i s being validated/filtered. 3 things can happen here: 1) worst case. He gets a good response for your database and receives some information(can't tell you what type since i don't know what db the form is connected to). 2) bad again. He gets an error message from the database which reveals information about how to continue. 3) desired case. You have filtered the input and nothing happened.

Comment: If you read my message, I specifically wrote: "I just would like to have a bit general knowledge of what they were trying to do."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They were hoping the textbox submitted data to a sql server and that the data was not filtered/sanitized. `1=1'` is a common method for testing for sql injection. The `x || ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 &` request is used for testing for shellshock vulnerability.

Answer to comment below:

By filtered/sanitized I mean using a method such as `htmlspecialchars`. I made 2 scripts especially for this answer. I have made a html and a php script that will demonstrate xss. Here is the html file.

> `<form name="form" action="https://localhost/poc.php" method="post">`
>
> `<div><b>Test Form</b></div>`
>
> `<input type="text" name="agentid" size="20"/>`
>   `<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">`
>
> `</form>`

And here is the php file ("poc.php")

> `<?php`
>
> `$test1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['agentid'], ENT_QUOTES);`
>
> `$test2 = $_POST['agentid'];`
>
> `echo 'this is not vulnerable<br>';`
>
> `echo $test1 . "<br>";`
>
> `echo 'this is vulnerable<br>';`
>
> `echo $test2;`
>
> `?>`

Go to the html page and type `<A HREF="http://this-is-a-test/">XSS</A>` in the text box and hit submit. You will see a link on the webpage. However you will notice the link will only be under the text that says "this is vulnerable". Take a look at the webpage source code and you will see one result is sanitized and the other is not.

Comment: What do you mean by 'filtered/sanitized' ?

Comment: I have updated my answer with an explanation above.

Answer (score 0):

It's possibly an automated scanner. If you google 0x7b5d, there are lots of results to suggest this, so to me it looks like an unskilled attacker trying some script or other.

They are hoping that your site will spit out an error message that they can then use to glean further information.